# iOS App Crash Report, How do I read it, what does it mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

One of my apps recently were rejected due to not running on iPad in compatibility mode. However, I fixed the problem and they load fine in Compatibility mode on iOS6 on my iPad simulator through xcode. So I reuploaded my app and about 7 hours later it already went into review and got rejected for the same reason, they said that the app crashed on iPad.

So, how do I read specifically the .crash file returned by apple?

Comment: See [Technical Note TN2151](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2151/_index.html) or search on `symbolicatecrash`.

Comment: I did, should I post it?